# To convert Powerpoint into outline of Tex-file effectively

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, latex, parsing

I have lectures as powerpoints.
I want to convert text and lists to tex-file.
If there is a picture, a mark can be left to a file.
I can individually add pictures.

I tried to save the ppt document into RF but there is much special syntax which parsing to tex can be cumbersome.

**What is an efficient way to get the outline of Powerpoint into tex-document?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any way to go directly from PPT to tex but if getting to a plain text file rather than RTF would be a more useful starting point, you could do it via macro or save as RTF, open in WordPad, select all, copy and paste into Notepad then save.

Comment: Yes, this was the solution which I eventually also choose the best one. RTF and then just copy paste to your tex editor.

Comment: Even better.  If you need to extract more than just the outline text (the text in those "Click here" blocks) you can do that with a macro.  I've got some example code on the PPT FAQ site I maintain.  Export Text to a text file, extract text from PowerPoint (Mac or PC)
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00274_Export_Text_to_a_text_file-_extract_text_from_PowerPoint_-Mac_or_PC-.htm